# This / that week

Tags: grammar

In response to:

> Only one week till I leave again. I'll miss you guys so much.

Is it:

> --Let's just enjoy **that** week and not think about the goodbye

or

> --Let's just enjoy **this** week and not think about the goodbye

Comment: In most normal contexts **this** but in some weird context maybe **that**,

Comment: Both are *technically correct* but, if you are referring to the current week, using *this* is much more common and will be more easily understood.

Answer (score 2):

Either.

The form using *that* would be interpreted as meaning "the week that you have just referred to".

The form using *this* would be interpreted as meaning "the week we are currently experiencing".

In this case it will mean the same thing.

In another context it might not:

> Okay, it's arranged now; we'll be away from the 14th until the 21st.

In this context, if spoken now (the 7th) "this week" would mean the week prior to the trip, because it's the week we're currently experiencing, while "that week" would mean the week of the trip, because it's the week that has just been mentioned.

When the two do coincide (as in your case), *this* would probably be more normal, but *that* could be used either simply because the speaker's mind focused more on the week as having been referenced, or to add emphasis.

Comment: The situation I was trying to construct was that someone has been visiting for quite a while (say a year) and realizes that he will have to say goodbye soon. Would "that" still be possible to refer to the upcoming 7 days before the goodbye, since they were referred to earlier? To me it sounds better than "this"...

Comment: My answer stands: *That* applies because it's just been referred to, and *this* applies because it is the week you are in, so you are free to choose between them. I agree that *that* sounds better, in adding a slight emphasis and keeping the conversation on the same referenced concept, so I would favour it, but *this* would also be allowed.

Comment: @JonHanna Technically, "this" could also be "the week you just referred to", though the more common usage of "this week" drowns out that sense of the word. For example: "Only one more bottle of wine left"..."Let's just enjoy this bottle of wine and not think about having to go to work in the morning."

Answer (score 0):

If you're 'in' the week, you would say *this* week.

Comment: And if one of you has already referenced a week, you would say *that* week. You're correct that you could use *this*, but you are incorrect in suggesting you couldn't use *that*.

Comment: When did I suggest you couldn't use _that_?

Comment: When someone asked whether one would use *this* or *that*, and you answered that one would use *this*.

Comment: You inferred that, I didn't suggest it. In any case, using _that week_ in the case of the example given "Only one week till I leave", _would_ be somewhat jarring, because the example suggests the week is already in progress.

Comment: So you are saying that when asked which of two possibilities is correct, answering that only one possibility is what one would use, in no way suggests a problem with the other? Interesting idea. In any case, using *that* week would have the slight advantage of focusing upon what has been said, emphasising it.

Comment: Indeed, whether the week has started or not seems irrelevant. "Enjoy that one week" - rather than focussing now on all the time after that when you will be missing us - seems absolutely fine. And yes, when I read "between A and B, you should use A", I also understand "do not use B" - but I guess I am a bit strange in that...

Comment: _That_ week suggests to me a week in the future. _This_ week suggests the current week. The example given above implies that we are in the week in question. If the final week was approaching, we might discuss it by saying "Let's make sure we really enjoy that final week". But saying that during the final week would just sound weird.